# Prime rich quadratic polynomials?

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

**Definition**

I want to find terms of the sequence that are the next smallest $A_n\in\mathbb N$ such that $f_{A_n}(x)=x^2+x+A_n$ is the prime richest quadratic polynomial so far; meaning it is richer in primes that all previous $f_{A_m},m\lt n,$ for all $x$ greater than some sufficiently large $x_0$.

If $\pi_A(n)$ is the number of primes produced by $f_A$ for $0\le x\le n$, then we say that 
$f_{A_1}$ is prime richer than $f_{A_2}$ at $n$ if: $\pi_{A_1}(n)\gt\pi_{A_2}(n) \text{ or } \pi_{A_1}(n)=\pi_{A_2}(n) \text{ and } A_1\lt A_2$ .

---

**Searching for terms**

Computing $\pi_A(10^5)$ for all $A\le41$ seems to imply that sequence starts as: $1,7,11,17,41,\dots$

All odd $A\le41$ sorted by "prime richness" based on *(sufficiently large?)* $\pi_A(10^5)$ below:

$$33, 15, 9, 21, 39, 3, 27, 13, 35, 19, 5, 25, 23, 1, 7, 31, 29, 37, 11, 17, 41$$

And the plot of $\pi_A(n)$ of these can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v17nG.png) for $n=0\dots10^5$, where $\pi_A$ that are less than $\pi_1$ are colored in gray,black and pink, and both $\pi_1$ and $\pi_{41}$ are colored in red.

For next terms there are candidates $\dots,21377, 27941, 41537, 55661,\dots$ based on a comment from this [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/search?q=41+21377+27941+41537+55661&sort=&language=english&go=Search); where I'm not sure why $154001$ is also mentioned as next best term after $55661$, since it does worse than the rest mentioned, in terms of $\pi_A(n)$; I suspect it is a typo?

These are only candidates because I'm not sure whether there are terms missing in between them; I suspect there might be terms in between $41,\dots,21377$, as I haven't started computing $\pi_A(n)$ for large enough $n$ yet, for $A\gt41$. But interestingly, they both are not far away on the graph in prime richness, so far.

I have plotted $\pi_A(n)$ for $n=0\dots10^5$ for all mentioned terms above:

[image]

The gap in prime richness between $f_{17},f_{41}$ is interesting.

Cyan and blue ($f_{27941},f_{41537}$) are seemingly overlapping, and it appears to be the same case as yellow,orange $(f_1,f_7)$; it's not clear if one is prime richer than the other, which is discussed next for the smaller case.

**Uncertainty among $1$ and $7$**

Notice $f_1,f_7$ seem to overlap, but $\pi_7$ beats $\pi_1$ with $10788\text{ to }10751$ primes, at $n=10^5$. Seems like $f_7$ is always better than $f_1$ for all $n\ge12756$, but only slightly, which accumulates to only a $37$ primes difference at $n=10^5$ as already mentioned.

I continued to compute $\pi_A(n)$ up to $n=10^6$ because it seemed like $f_1$ could overtake $f_7$ again.

Indeed, at $n=120939$, $f_1$ overtakes in prime richness, and $\pi_1,\pi_7$ keep interchanging until $n=157782$, where $\pi_7$ continues the lead again with a fluctuating slight prime advantage.

At $n=750573$, $f_1$ again overtakes in prime richness and $\pi_1,\pi_7$ continue interchanging the lead again. But surprisingly, after $n=846279$, $\pi_1$ now overtakes lead for the first time for a longer period which is up to $10^6$ so far and counting.

Exact standings so far are: $\pi_1(10^6)=88118$ and $\pi_7(10^6)=88106$, only $12$ primes difference.

Seems like computing larger $\pi_A(n)$ here won't help.

> Now I'm not sure whether there exists some sufficiently large $n_0$
>   such that $\pi_7(n)\gt\pi_1(n)$ for all $n\ge n_0$? Is it possible to
>   show if this is the case or not?

Since this, by initial definition, says whether the sequence starts as $1,7,11,17,41$ or $1,11,17,41$

---

**Computing more terms**

I wanted to do a "brute force" and compute $\pi_A(n)$ for all odd $A$ in between the candidate terms so far up to some large $n$ to sort them out and confirm whether terms are missing or not, but this seems like it's taking extremely slow with my naive c++ code. I suspect it is redundant to check composite $A$, but even considering only $A$ that are prime or a product of two primes, it is still very slow going when aiming for larger $n$ and more of $A$'s.

> Is it possible to find terms of this sequence efficiently and with more certainty?
>
> Are there software or programming tools once could utilize to perform this task?

What so far is known about prime rich quadratics of form $f_A=x^2+x+A$?

---

**Remark**

But even with decent efficiency, computing large $\pi_A(n)$ does not help in cases such as $f_1,f_7$ and $f_{27941},f_{41537}$, which both have interchanging and leading periods. It seems that in both cases we will have interchanging periods occur infinitely many times, but I suspect this is hard to show.

For simplicity, if we have behavior such as $\pi_C\lt\pi_A\approx\pi_B\lt\pi_D$ for all $n$ greater than some sufficiently large $n_0$,  where $A\lt B$, then then the sequence goes $\dots,C,A,B,D,\dots$

Thus, so far we would have $1,7,11,17,41,\dots?\dots,21377,27941,41537,55661,\dots$

I'm mainly interested in finding more terms.

Comment: Do you search the record holders, or just other $A$ with a large number of primes ?

Comment: @Peter Just other $A$ with large number of primes: I'm hoping to list and find a sequence of all $A$ that increases in efficiency of producing primes up to some larger term; as the question currently stands: I'm looking into whether there are any terms in between $41,21377$,  and primarily how to efficiently get terms coming after $55661$ which is the current largest term closest to the previous terms I've listed.

Comment: For $A=115\ 721$ we get $37\ 059$ primes which, according to my calculations, beats $55\ 661$ with $35\ 886$ primes. Please check!

Comment: Record holders for $n=1000$ tend to be record holders also for $n=10^5$, the next record holder for $n=1000$ is $247\ 757$ with $657$ primes and in fact for $n=10^5$ we have $39\ 759$ primes

Comment: @Peter I've just stumbled upon [this unrelated answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2148326) that mentions $247 757$ which has $39759$ primes at $\pi(10^5)$; I've plotted now [55661,115721,247757](https://i.imgur.com/pwMrshX.png) for $n=0...10^5$ which are at $(35886,37059,39759)$, and indeed it seems that $115 721$ is very likely the next term after $55661$,! I'm not sure if there could also be a term in between $115721,247757$.

Comment: I calculated what you posted independent with PARI/GP

Comment: At least the record holders for $n=1000$ can fast be determined, of course they need not be a record holder for larger values, but at least they are good candidates.

Comment: @Peter I appreciate your comments and insight!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79862/discussion-between-peter-and-vepir).